# The angle of kite

Tags: geometry

[image]
How can i find the value of $x $ ?
I have tried the sum of the quadrilaterals but i got three unknowns and two equations ?

Comment: Clearly some info is missing

Comment: I don't see what information is assumed about the side lengths or the other angles ... Is the picture even a flat 2D?

Comment: yes it is flat 2D @Matti P.

Comment: Unless some extra information is given, I don't see how this could be solved. I imagine that the side lengths (the two sides with the acute angle) could be elongated in a way that would keep $y$ costant but change the value of $x$. Weird ...

Comment: Not accurately drawn to say the least. Two kites whose short sides are equal placed in such a way would create an intersection that is a triangle, not this pentagon that they have pictured. The question is ill-posed, since the angle y would not even exist, since its adjacent sides are non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry of the diagram, we see that the left vertex has an angle of 90+x

By symmetry of the kite we see that the angle below y is also 90+x. We now have 5 sides of the pentagon.
(90+x) + (90+x) + 90 + 90 + y = 540
Gives 2x + y = 180

Let z be the tip of the kite:
From the angles around a kite we have z=90-2x

Unless there is additional information from part a) I see no way to progress from here